# No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una encuesta donde, tiene obviamente su pregunta (question) y sus posibles respuestas, que en casos solo puede tener `1`, `2` o mas , posteriormente
se encuentra la respuesta elegida (`resp_elegida`)

El siguiente es mi `JSON`:

```
[{
    "id": "87050",
    "question": "1.- XXXXXX",
    "resp_uno": " A) XXXX",
    "resp_dos": " B) XXXX",
    "resp_tres": {},
    "resp_cuatro": {},
    "resp_cinco": {},
    "resp_seleccionada": "1",
    "comentario": "",
    "sub": "14"
}, {
    "id": "87050",
    "question": "2.- XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "resp_uno": " A) XXXXXX",
    "resp_dos": " B) XXXXXXX",
    "resp_tres": " C) XXXXXX",
    "resp_cuatro": " D) XXXXXXX",
    "resp_cinco": {},
    "resp_elegida": "1",
    "comentario": "",
    "sub_area": "14"
}]
```

Esta es la clase con las propiedades:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string question { get; set; }
public string resp_uno { get; set; }
public string resp_dos { get; set; }
public string resp_tres { get; set; }
public string resp_cuatro { get; set; }
public string resp_cinco { get; set; }
public int resp_elegida { get; set; }
public string comentario { get; set; }
public string sub { get; set; }
```

Cuando llega a mi function de guardado hacia la base de datos, la
primera linea es `Deserializar` el `JSON`, pero cuando llega a esta me da el siguiente error:

linea:

```
var JsonRequest = js.Deserialize<List<Ex.Models.EXP_RESP_MODEL>>(JSON);
```

Error:

> System.MissingMethodException:  No parameterless constructor defined
> for type of 'System.String'.'

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Verifica que `JSON` sea una de tipo cadena y si tu modelo contiene definida las mismas propiedades de tu json.

Ejemplo:

```
public class _MODEL{
 public List<detalle> data {get; set;}
}
public class detalle{
  public string id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
}

string json =@"{""data"":[{""id"":""11"",""name"":""name""}]}";
var JsonRequest = js.Deserialize<Exa.Models._MODEL>(json);
```